# Is it possible to hide the source codes of .m files and build project using xcodebuild

Tags: iphone, macos

I have created a Mac app that can generate iphone ebook app project source codes. 
I know I can using xcodebuild to build the project to get the release binary file.
Is it possible to hide the source codes of .m files(maybe store in memory) and build project using xcodebuild?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are attempting to generate source code for others to use, but then hide it so they cannot see whats been generated. Basically not possible. You could generate obfuscated code which would make it harder to read, but not impossible.

Realistically what you are trying to do is generate template code for others to use. If you don't want them to be able to see it, then you presumably don't want them modifying it. The easiest answer is to simple not do it. Instead, create a compile static framework containing your code and IP, and then only generate templates which makes calls to your framework. Thus your code is protected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have explained to me everything

Answer (score 1):

Your question lives on the edge of being programming related, and I'm not exactly sure what problem you're trying to solve.

However, you can [create a RAM disk](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/23/create-a-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/), store your project there and run `xcodebuild` against that. Just be aware that you're not really protecting the `.m` files so much as limiting how long they are easily visible.